# magento 1 price display on PDP with additional cost and select options

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-attribute, custom-options

I have different requirement that shows the product price in multiple way.
[image]

As per the image product should contain Base price, Installation price and GST. Along with that multiple custom option and price should be updated on selection of each.

What is the best approach to achieve this and is there any extension for this?